# Python print array in an order

Tags: python

from the following array how can i get an output as stated

```
arr=["harry","sally","tom"]

harry
harry
harry
sally
sally
tom

sally
sally
sally
tom
tom
harry

tom
tom
tom
harry
harry
sally
```

what ive tried

```
>>> for i in range(len(arr)):
...     print arr[i] * 3
...     print arr[i+1]*2
...     print arr[i-1] 
... 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Do you understand _why_ you're getting an `IndexError`? Think about what happens when `i` is `0` and the code tries to access `arr[i-1]`.

Comment: I know the indexing error i just showed my code what i tried at the spur of the moment

Comment: @MattBall, when he tries to access `arr[i-1]` with `i==0` it actually does what he wanted. It's only the `i+1` that doesn't wrap round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the modulus operator to wrap around to the beginning of the list, or double the list but use the length of the original.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> for i in range(len(arr)):
        print arr[i % len(arr)] * 3
        print arr[(i+1) % len(arr)] * 2
        print arr[(i+2) % len(arr)] * 1
```